# How to set properties of the initial search with Vue InstantSearch?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, algolia

I'm using the Vue components provided by Algolia to search my index.

https://v2--vue-instantsearch.netlify.com/getting-started/getting-started.html

The search works just fine but I'm wondering how I can set the initial values of say, the refinement list I have on page load.

I set the search up like so:

```
<script>
import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch/lite'

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  data () {
    return {
      searchClient: algoliasearch(
        'APPID',
        'API-KEY'
      )
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

...and I have a refinement list like so (lots of code cut out for brevity):

```
<ais-instant-search
  :search-client="searchClient"
  index-name="properties"
>
  <ais-refinement-list
    attribute="borough"
    :sortBy="['name:asc']"
  />
</ais-instant-search>
```

As soon as I land on the page, all checkboxes for the refinement list are blank...I'd like to know how I can set some initial values / combinations for a query of my liking.

Is it even possible using these components? I have looked through the docs quite extensively but I'm not sure I can see anything detailing this. Perhaps I'm searching for the wrong terms.

Help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Looking at [this](https://github.com/algolia/vue-instantsearch/blob/master/src/components/RefinementList.vue) it doesn't seem possible without forking the component.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 ways for get its:

1. Set default value en `ais-searcher routing`, as:

```
...

routeToState: (routeState) => {
  if(!routeState.foo) {
    routeState.foo = this.bar
  }
  ...
```

2. Use a `ref` in your refine components and execute its methods:

```
// in template
<ais-refinement-list
  attribute="foo"
  ref="fooRefinement" />

// In Script

...
mounted() {
  this.$refs.fooRefinement.refine('bar')
}
```

In this last, you should use promises or `setInterval` for wait the method.